# Integrate Twitter posts from specific person on iOS app on table view

Tags: ios, swift, post, twitter

I have to implement all Twitter posts of one person to my table view and automatically update when that person publishes a new one. also, second part would be mentions(@person) of the person. How can I do it? Is there a very easy way, or I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can do this, is by using Twitters built in service called Fabric.

Go check out fabric.io for more information on how to use it, specifically [this documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/show-timelines.html) for timeline related stuff.

If you want a step by step tutorial on how to add a specific person's timeline, I made a video on how to do this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODTNtwnk6_E). :)

[Here](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/show-timelines.html#search-timeline) is the documentation needed to display everyone that mentions the user. :)

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much, Jared.